# Kubernetes ConfigMap automatically changes Literal to Folded Block Scalar

Tags: yaml, openshift, configmap

I'm having problems with ConfigMap creation on OpenShift 4. I'm trying to add a data element which holds Java `application.properties` and to format the YAML using literal block scalar. Example:

```
data:
  application.properties: |
    spring.application.name=myApp
    server.port=8080
    management.server.port=8080
```

Everything works fine until I add a longer line which should be present in the `application.properties`. After I save the change literal block scalar is automatically updated to folded block scalar, like this:

```
data:
  application.properties: >
    spring.application.name=myApp

    server.port=8080

    management.server.port=8080

    some.long.property=this.is.some.long.property.value.which.should.be.part.of.the.properties.file
```

What is the cause of this and how can I fix it? Its really frustrating.

Comment: What happens if you add a minus sign (-) after the style indicator, that is |-

Comment: Same thing happens, after I hit the save button it just converts to folded block scalar with minus sign. >-

Answer (score 0):

It seems a behaviour of Openshift Web Console, it changes the yaml style when you use longer data.

If you try to change it from oc

```
oc edit configmap YOURCM
```

you can see the style won't change. If you don't want this problem probably you should create directly from oc using

```
oc create configmap YOURCM --from-file=application.properties
```